# PostgreSQL Row Level Security in Node JS

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, node-postgres, row-level-security

I have a database which is shared amongst multiple tenants/users. However, I want to add row-level-security protection so that any given tenant can only see those rows that belong to them.

As such, for each tenant I have a user in PostgreSQL, such as "client_1" and "client_2". In each table, there is a column "tenant_id", the default value of which is "session_user".

Then, I have row level security as such:

```
CREATE POLICY policy_warehouse_user ON warehouse FOR ALL
TO PUBLIC USING (tenant_id = current_user);
ALTER TABLE warehouse ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
This works great, and if I set the user "SET ROLE client_1" I can only access those rows in which the tenant_id = "client_1".
```

However, I am struggling with how to best set this up in the Node JS back-end. Imortantly, for each tenant, such as "client_1", there can be multiple users connected. So several users on our system, all who work at company X, will connect to the database as "client_1".

What I am currently doing is this:

```
let config = {
        user: 'test_client2',
        host: process.env.PGHOST,
        database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
        max: 10, //default value
        password: 'test_client2',
        port: process.env.PGPORT,
    }

const pool = new Pool(config);
const client = await pool.connect()

await client.query('sql...')

client.release();
```

I feel like this might be a bad solution, especially since I am creating a new Pool each time a query is executed. So the question is, how can I best ensure that each user executes queries in the database using the ROLE that corresponds to their tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a `setupDatabase` method that returns the pool for your app this will be called once at app bootstrap:

```js
function setUpDatabase {
  let config = {
    user: 'test_client2',
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    max: 10, //default value
    password: 'test_client2',
    port: process.env.PGPORT,
  }

  const pool = new Pool(config);
  return pool
}
```

and then when you identify the tenant before executing the query you set the role

```js
await client.query('set role $tenant', currentTenant);
// my assumption is that next line will use the role you set before
await client.query('select * from X where Y');
```

This is just a suggestion, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Good idea, I will try that. Then I would have to set-up a middleware for all queries to always set the role before executing any query.

Comment: this wont work in case of concurrent request.